# How to use a web form with JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jsp, jax-rs

I am new to JAX-RS and so far I have created a simple CRUD REST service for my model `Entity` which has some `String` and `Float` attributes.

Right now this is how I can create a new `Entity`:

```
@Path("/entities")
public class EntityController {
    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/json"})
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public Entity createEntity(Entity entity) {
        if (EntityDAO.createEntity(entity) return entity,
        else return null;
    }
}
```

And this works just fine.

However, as I go forward into this API I would like to be able to make a simple form (in jsp I guess) to submit and create a new `Entity`.

I have seen some answers to similar problems [here](http://blog.usul.org/using-jsp-in-a-jersey-jax-rs-restful-application/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974191/jax-rs-rest-services-working-fine-how-to-add-jsp-pages-stuck-with-configuratio), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984338/how-to-forward-from-a-jax-rs-service-to-jsp) or [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html). However, as I am new to JAX-RS and web services actually, I cannot decipher what's going on.

I would like some help and I'd really appreciate if you could point out all the components that take part into the given solution in case I am missing an obvious step.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`@FormParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html) to inject form data:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Produces("...")
public Entity proceedForm(@FormParam("name") String name,
                          @FormParam("age") int age) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: where should I store the html form in my project tree? I am guessing to access it from the browser I will have to set up some kind of resources in some xml file, right?

Comment: If you're using tomcat, place html or jsp file in `WebContent` folder

Comment: Or you can create one more @GET method which @Produces("text/html") to return this page directly from service

Comment: and how can I access the html file under `WebContent` from the browser? `localhost:8080/projectName/form.html` doesn't work. Do I need to set up anything else?

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing your environment, servlet and jax-rs provider and so on

Comment: what do you need to know?